# Sharing stdout among multiple threads/processes

Tags: linux, multithreading, stdout

I have a linux program(the language doesn't matter) which prints it's log onto stdout.
The log IS needed for monitoring of the process.

Now I'm going to parallelize it by fork'ing or using threads.

**The problem: resulting stdout will contain unreadable mix of unrelated lines...**

And finally **The question: How would you re-construct the output logic for parallel processes ?**

Comment: Do you want to split the log into separate per-process/thread logs, or do you only want to avoid mixing output from several processes _within_ a line?

Comment: It should be visually separated per-process. So the user could understand the status of every task. Atomic lines is a minor problem, I'll just use some synchronization object.

Comment: Tag your log lines with something unique per process, e.g. `[process-$PID]` or `[roleOfTheProcess]`?

Comment: +1 As one of the possible approaches... Still looking for a method to separate the output into sub-logs per process.

Comment: You can tag and later filter by tags into sublogs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for answering myself...

**The definite solution was to use the [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) utility.**

It came to replace the well known `xargs` utility, but runs the commands in parallel, separating the output into groups.

So I just left my simple one-process, one-thread utility as-is and piped its call through the `parallel` like that:

> generate-argument-list | parallel < options > my-utility

This, depending on parallel's options can produce nicely grouped outputs for multiple calls of `my-utility`

Answer (score 3):

Another approach, which we use, is to delegate a thread, logger thread, for logging. All other threads wishing to log will send it to logger thread. This method gives you flexibility as formatting of logs can be done is single place, which can also be configurable. If you don't want to worry about locks can use sockets for message passing.

Answer (score 2):

If its multithreaded, then you'll need to mutex protect printing/writing to the stdout log. The most common way to do this in Linux and c/c++ is with pthread_mutex. Additionally, if its c++, boost has synchronization that could be used.

To implement it, you should probably encapsulate all the logging in one function or object, and internally lock and unlock the mutex.

If logging blocking performance becomes prohibitive, you could consider buffering the log messages (in the afore mentioned object or function) and only writing to stdout when the buffer is full. You'll still need mutex protection to buffer, but buffering will be faster than writing to stdout.

If each thread will have its own logging messages, then they will still need to all share the same mutex for writing to stdout. In this case it would probably be best for each thread to buffer its respective log messages and only write to stdout when the the buffer is full, thus only obtaining the mutex for writing to stdout.

Answer (score 2):

If you're in C++ I'd consider using [Pantheios](http://www.pantheios.org/) or derivative version Boost::Log or using look at [Logging In C++ : Part 2](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/221900468) or

If you're in another language then file locking around the IO operations is probably the way to go see [File Locks](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/File-Locks.html), you can achieve the same results using semaphonres or any other process control system but for me file locks are the easiest.

You could also consider using [syslog](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Syslog-Example.html#Syslog-Example) if this monitoring is considered as system wide.