# Confusing output on multithreaded programming

Tags: python, multithreading, output, python-multithreading

I've wrote this simple program that creates a thread and runs a method:

```
import threading

class MyThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, thread_name, counter):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.thread_name = thread_name
        self.counter = counter

    def printIteration(self, counter):
        it = 1

        while counter > 0:
            print "\n"+self.thread_name+": Iteration", it,"\n"
            it += 1
            counter -= 1

    def run(self):
        print "\n"+self.thread_name+" started...\n"
        self.printIteration(self.counter)
        exit()


my_thread1 = MyThread("Thread1", 2)
my_thread2 = MyThread("Thread2", 4)

my_thread1.start()
my_thread2.start()
```

But, when i run it, the output is something like:

```
Thread1 started...
Thread2 started...

Thread1: Iteration
Thread2: Iteration 1 1
.
.
.
```

Why? It's normal or i've forgot something?

Comment: It's common for the multithread application that the outputs can interleave. You can check e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928115/sharing-stdout-among-multiple-threads-processes for details.

Comment: Thank you! But now i've another question: there is a python's module that can help me to reorganize the output?

Comment: Try to print with lock http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects

Comment: Thank you, i'll try this...i think it should fix the problem.